# Adding .cache() to (Py)Spark dataframe ignores .limit() and caches complete dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm writing up a pipeline for a very large dataframe. In order to rapidly prototype, I'm trying to cache a small amount of samples from the dataframe.

My expectation was that I could efficiently achieve this by executing the code below.

```py
df.limit(1).cache().collect()
```

However, as shown in the picture below, this creates two stages of which the first one caches the complete dataframe (toy example of 99.3gb).

[Spark stages with cache()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRAAI.png)

This is surprising, because when I remove the cache method (leaving `df.limit(1).collect()`), spark spawns a collect stage that is only applied on a single partition in my dataframe. See picture below.

[Spark stages without cache()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIkIb.png)

This same different is also observed when comparing the stages when combining limit with show/collect/take (stage with one partition) vs count (stage with full dataframe).

Although I can speed up this cache by filtering out a single partition manually, I'm still stuck with the following two questions:

1. What is the most efficient way of caching a sample of data from a large dataframe?
2. Why is .cache() caching the complete dataframe when a limit is placed on the query, while the same query without cache() doesn't touch the complete dataframe?